# Homograph challenge

Tags: meaning-in-context, homographs

My friend said the other day, "I hate when a sentence starts with the word polish, because you don't know whether they mean polish or Polish."

```
polish (v) - to make smooth and glossy
Polish (a) - originating from Poland
```

I'm trying to think of a sentence where either word in the same spot would still make sense, but due to them being 2 different forms of speech I'm at a loss.  Better yet, could it be the first word of the sentence?

Edit: both words can take noun form, I knew that but for some reason didn't think of that before/while posting.  Obviously this is in the context of reading, so spelling is most important.

Comment: This is probably cheating but "'Polish' can make a sentence hard to pronounce".

Comment: This is actually an example of a heteronym - same spelling, different pronunciation. Maybe consider editing your title for the general "homograph" - which includes both homonyms and heteronyms.

Comment: Sue Taylor, the shoemaker of Oxford St.(verb, imperative, asking Sue to sue Taylor)
Sue Taylor, the shoemaker of Oxford St. (surname, a shoemaker named Sue Taylor)

Comment: **Minute men appeared out of nowhere** [uses *minute* as in small and *minute* as in the context of the American Revolution, which featured citizen-soldiers who were "ready in a minute"].

Comment: @Jo Or even “May Sue Ta[i/y]lor Jones die”—a die in the shape of a woman called May Sue Taylor Jones, a hope that Sue Taylor Jones dies, a statement that I might sue a die shaped like Taylor Jones, or a statement that I might sue a die shaped like a tailor named Jones. (Works better orally, obviously.)

Comment: Polish has changed beyond all recognition over the last century.

Comment: For homographs, please consult the U.S. Census Bureau. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a list game with no real answer

Comment: It was somewhat of a word game, but not one with no real answer.  Note that the accepted answer was the first to accomplish what was asked, making the two words interchangeable in a written sentence.  Other answers may or may not have been quite as on-topic, but obviously this post was more for fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you include the noun **polish**:

> Polish (n) - a substance that is rubbed on a surface to make it smooth and shiny

Then you could have this:

- *Polish it is, but affordable it definitely is not!*

Otherwise, I fear you're stuck with something along the lines of:

- *Polish or not, it's entirely up to you.*

If you'll consider signs and notes, then there is of course this - which could be either a sign on the door of a Warsaw student at the University of Istanbul, or a note to self by an overzealous contestant in a domestic wildfowl fancying competition:

- *Polish Turkey!*

Answer (score 18):

I suppose in very brief telegram style, it could be done.

*Check/Czech* is sadly the other way around (heterographs, rather than homophones); otherwise a note written to the domestic staff that they should only look in on the silverware, never attempt to clean it themselves could also be taken as instructions only to buy silverware from the Czech Republic, never from Poland:

> ***Check silverware, never polish!*** / ***Czech silverware, never Polish!***

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but definitely amazing!  I lol'd

Answer (score 5):

I’m not sure whether you want answers focusing on the words “polish”/”Polish”,
or whether you’re looking for homographs in general. 
If you’re looking at the general case, the classic (humorous) example is

> Time flies?   You can’t; they fly too fast.

where your first impression of the first two words, “Time flies”,
is the old motto that **time** (noun) seems to go by quickly (**flies**, verb). 
But then the second sentence casts the first one in a new light:

> Can you time flies?

in which **time** is a verb (as in “Time me while I run to the store and back.”)
and **flies** are flying insects (noun).

---

Oh!  I just remembered a related one:

> Time flies like an arrow.   Fruit flies like a banana.

where the first three words are different parts of speech in the two sentences
(if you’re willing to consider “fruit” to be an adjective in “fruit flies”).

Comment: I'm specifically looking for polish/Polish, but this post is more about fun plays on words anyways :)

Comment: Periodic acid burns are only to be expected.

Answer (score 5):

Polish products have soared in price recently. The pumice mines near Krakow are on strike!

Answer (score 4):

It may be easier if you recognise that 'polish' is also a noun, and then use it as a noun adjunct so it takes the same place in a sentence as an adjective.

So, something like,

"Polish colours of red & white are now available."

Comment: But _Polish_ is also a noun: "I'll have a Polish with sauerkraut on the side, please."

Comment: @JohnLawler Is that like at a lap dancing club? The one on the side never smiles? You are the Chuck Norris of heterographs.

Comment: I don't know. But _having a Polish_ is one of the most popular things about Costco in the US.

Comment: @JohnLawler Now I'm not sure if you're being witty or if "sauerkraut" just doesn't travel well from the UK to the US. Probably best to go no further.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I usually have my Polish with Ginger and Olives (the more the merrier), and after throw in a Mary Jane.

Comment: @Frank: From this context, I'd say JohnLawler is having a Polish **sausage**.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer lies in a joke. 
Warning: this is ethnic and may be considered insensitive/offensive.

> The dumb guy from Warsaw thought his wife was planning to kill him
> because he saw that she had bought a bottle of Polish Remover.

Answer (score 0):

Context: theater call board.

> Polish rehearsal for Act II will be Friday.

In actual practice it more usually takes the non-sentence form:

> Friday 6 June 7:00 p.m.: Act II – Polish.

. . . and we would always try to gull the noobs into thinking it meant we all had to speak our lines in Polish.

Answer (score 0):

> Polish removers are made from acetone
>
> Polish removers are made from Nazis.

I still don't understand the confusion.  `Polish`, as in someone/something from Poland, uses the actual O sound from the alphabet, while, `polish`, the verb, is pronounced `Pah-lish`

Comment: It had to do with the written form, specifically my friend had mentioned reading.